# Flexbox fallback. Floating columns display table + table-cell

Tags: html, css

GOAL: Columns same height regardless of content. I have these cards that I want all the same height regardless of their content.

I want to be able to use display: flex; but due to my need for support for lower than IE8 I cannot. My code snippet shows the grid I am working with.

```css
.row {
  display: table;
}

.row .one {
  width: 6.475%;
}

.row .two {
  width: 14.975%;
}

.row .three {
  width: 23.475%;
}

.row .four {
  width: 31.975%;
}

.row .five {
  width: 40.475%;
}

.row .six {
  width: 48.975%;
}

.row .seven {
  width: 57.475%;
}

.row .eight {
  width: 65.975%;
}

.row .nine {
  width: 74.475%;
}

.row .ten {
  width: 82.975%;
}

.row .eleven {
  width: 91.475%;
}

.row .twelve {
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: table-cell;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column:last-child {
  float: right;
}

.card {
  background: #fefefe;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-left: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="nine column card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div class="three column card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.
  </div>
</div>
```

If you make the parent display: flex it works perfectly but I need the fallback for the older browsers.

NOTE: I am aware the problem is that I have floating columns BUT this cannot be changed (I am merely adding a small presentation enhancement, I am unable to change the whole grid of the framework I am using).

I would like to know if there is a way around this problem?

https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/ Of all the solutions in this article using table and table-cell is a very quick fix but it doesn't work because my columns are floating left (again I can't change this).

Has anyone come across this problem? Is Javascript the only fallback avaiable?

Answer (score 0):

One-way is to force min-height and max-height to your divs inside the row with same values. But you will need overflow to prevent your contents going outside the element.

```css
.row {
  display: table;
  
}
.row div{
 max-height:100px;
  min-height:100px;
 overflow:auto;
}

.row .one {
  width: 6.475%;
}

.row .two {
  width: 14.975%;
}

.row .three {
  width: 23.475%;
}

.row .four {
  width: 31.975%;
}

.row .five {
  width: 40.475%;
}

.row .six {
  width: 48.975%;
}

.row .seven {
  width: 57.475%;
}

.row .eight {
  width: 65.975%;
}

.row .nine {
  width: 74.475%;
}

.row .ten {
  width: 82.975%;
}

.row .eleven {
  width: 91.475%;
}

.row .twelve {
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: table-cell;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column:last-child {
  float: right;
}

.card {
  background: #fefefe;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-left: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="nine column card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div class="three column card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.
  </div>
</div>
```